# Hadoop: Is it possible to avoid replication for certain files?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, replication

In hdfs as i understand all files are replicated, but we do certain logging in case of our jobs, the files of which we donot want replication as it might unnecessarily maintain replicated copies, is it possible to do so? i.e to avoid only log files being replicated.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set replicaion by using -setrep flag along with hadoop fs shell command.

```
Usage: hadoop fs -setrep [-R] [-w] <numReplicas> <path>

Changes the replication factor of a file. If path is a directory then the command recursively changes the replication factor of all files under the directory tree rooted at path.

Options:

The -w flag requests that the command wait for the replication to complete. This can potentially take a very long time.
The -R flag is accepted for backwards compatibility. It has no effect.
Example:

hadoop fs -setrep -w 3 /user/hadoop/dir1
```

To avoid replication you can set numReplicas to 1.

Comment: Thanks for the reply venkata, But i wanted to know if it is possible to set replication factor ONLY FOR CERTAIN FILES and not the entire file system. Is there are way for that?

Comment: Yes, what i have mentioned is for just one file. If you want to set for entire file system you have to change in property file.